# Java create directory and subdirectory if not exist

Tags: java

Let's assume I want to create the `generatedAnswers` directory which contains another directory `dirName` which is a String variable I input.

Then I want to insert `fileName` in the directory `generatedAnswers/dirName" such that the file falls in the dirName directory as per the following structure:

```
/ generatedAnswers
   /dirName
     fileName.txt
```

I tried the following code but it does not work:

```
File file = new File("generatedQuestions/"+dirName+"/");
file.getParentFile().mkdirs();

PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(file+fileName+".txt");
```

The result I'm getting is:
/generatedAnswers
dirNamefineName.txt (this turned into the filename)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use this code :

```
File file = new File("generatedQuestions/"+dirName+"/");
file.getParentFile().mkdirs();

PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(file.getAbsolutePath() +fileName+".txt");
```

I add file.getAbsolutePath(), because u try get file path

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
String dirName = "someDirectory";
String fileName = "file.txt";
File file = new File("generatedQuestions/" + dirName + "/" + fileName);
if(file.getParentFile().mkdirs()) {
    PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(file);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing wrong is in this line of your code:

```java
file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
```

The `file` path is `generatedQuestions/dirName`, so `file.getParentFile()` returns `generatedQuestions` and you call `mkdirs()` on that, hence you are only creating directory `generatedQuestions` and not the sub-directory, `dirName`. Remove the `getParentFile()`, i.e. just

```java
file.mkdirs()
```

Note that `mkdirs()` may fail, in which case it will return false. You should check the return value and not assume that it always succeeds.

Finally the argument to `PrintWriter` constructor is also wrong. The `toString()` method of class `java.io.File` does **not** print the trailing separator character so you need to add that, i.e.

```java
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(file + File.separator + fileName+".txt");
```

The following code worked for me.

```java
String dirName = "dirName";
File file = new File("generatedQuestions" + File.separator + dirName);
if (file.mkdirs()) {
    String fileName = "fileName";
    try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(file + File.separator + fileName+".txt")) {
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException x) {
        x.printStackTrace();
    }
}
else {
    System.out.println("'mkdirs()' failed.");
}
```

Alternatively, you could use a combination of interface [Path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) and class [Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) like so.

```java
Path path = Paths.get("generatedQuestions", dirName);
try {
    Files.createDirectories(path);
    path = path.resolve(fileName + ".txt");
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(path.toFile());
}
catch (IOException x) {
    x.printStackTrace();
}
```